# Install older version of PHP in CentOS

Tags: centos, php, apache-1.3

There is a web server with CentOS 6.2, Apache 1.3.12 and PHP 4.0.1pl2. It was hosting a web site and now I am trying to host this site on CentOS 6.5, but the site is not working properly. Is it because of newer version of PHP 5.3 and Apache?  So, should I install the older version of PHP 4.0.1pl2?

Answer (score 2):

No. Absolutely NOT. You should NOT allow such an ancient version of PHP on any network, especially not on the Internet. It'll have a lifetime of minutes before it's hacked.

Instead, update or replace the PHP application.

Comment: Because there aren't major corporate websites all over the internet running 5.3 . . . .